# Download xlsx file without Headers, Vuejs

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios, export-to-excel

I have a download action, that it works, but in my .xlsx file I don't have the header, and I am not sure how can I get them. I'm using Vuejs / Axios with Laravel.

```
<a type="button" class="mr-3" href="/json/persons/export" download="file.xlsx">
<button @click="exportCSV" class="btn btn-primary">
    Export CSV
</button>
</a>

exportCSV() {
    axios
    .get("/json/persons/export", {
        params: {
        sort_by: this.sortBy,
        sort_direction: this.sortDesc
        }
    })
    .then(response => {
        //
    })
    .catch(error => {
        //
    });
},
```

**Export Class Code**

```
namespace App\Exports;
use App\ViewData;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;
use Excel;

class DataExport implements FromCollection
{
    public function collection()
    {
        return ViewData::all();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Well you can actually do something like**

```
namespace App\Exports;
use App\ViewData;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadings;
use Excel;

class DataExport implements FromCollection, WithHeadings
{
    public function collection()
    {
        return ViewData::all();
    }

    //Define your desired headings this way, it's just for an example
    public function headings(): array
    {
       return [
           'Name',
           'Surname',
           'Email',
           'Twitter',
       ];
    }
}
```

Comment: Best, thank's a lot! Ps. I think that you should place an answer to the other question.

Comment: Yeah let me place answer to the question as well. Welcome

Comment: Posted that answer to your question too. please check that as well